# How to set or change export area in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I got from designer an Illsutrator file, and it is well setup, I can aoutomatically export to 1024x1024 from each logo type, but I also need a different size. I see in the file a square, I think this determines the export area, how can I change it? :)

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 2):

When exporting, untick **Use Artboards** (or **Clip to Artboard** if saving for web) to export using the bounds of the actual artwork.

You can also adjust the artboard size by using the *Artboard Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)

You can even export as a square and then crop if needed in a photo editing software.

Comment: You can always change the artboard as well.